# Match Criteria and Paste Transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will match an ID number (Column D) and match it to a series listed in Column B.  For all the matches, I want to be able to copy the code in column A and paste it into Sheet2 transposed, with the original ID number (column D) in the first column.  I have a code that mostly works.

```
Sub History()

    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
    Dim loop_ctr As Integer

    'Start search in row 4
    LSearchRow = 4

    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2
    columnncopy = 2
    A = A

        While Len(Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

        For loop_ctr = 4 To 4

            'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
             If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = Range("G" & loop_ctr) Then

                'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
                Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
                Selection.Copy

                'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Range("A" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
                'CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste



                'Move counter to next row
                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

                'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
                Sheets("Sheet1").Select

            End If

            LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

              Next loop_ctr

         Wend



    'Position on cell A3
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A3").Select

    'MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

The trouble with this code is that I can't figure out how to make the code move over one column at a time. I know it works if I manually go in and change it to "B", but how do I do it automatically?

Range("A" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select

My other issue is that this isn't transposing the paste.  I can do that in a second step, but I feel like there is a much simpler code that should be able to do it all at one step by finding the upper and lower bounds of the range that matches the criteria.  Any suggestsion?

```
Date     ID Number      Find    Paste matching dates horizontally       
1/12/2005   PTA123      PTA123          
1/2/2007    PTA123      PTA456          
1/31/2007   PTA123      PTA786          
2/28/2007   PTA123                  
5/23/2007   PTA123                  
6/20/2007   PTA123                  
6/3/2009    PTA123                  
7/2/2009    PTA123                  
7/1/2014    PTA123                  
8/4/2014    PTA123                  
9/11/2014   PTA123                  
10/23/2014  PTA123                  
12/4/2014   PTA123                  
2/13/2013   PTA456                  
3/13/2013   PTA456                  
4/10/2013   PTA456                  
5/10/2013   PTA456                  
6/7/2013    PTA456                  
7/22/2013   PTA456                  
10/7/2010   PTA786                  
11/4/2010   PTA786                  
12/2/2010   PTA786                  
12/30/2010  PTA786                  
1/28/2011   PTA786                  
2/25/2011   PTA786
```

Comment: Will the data always be sorted on column B, as in are the ID Numbers always grouped together?

Comment: If they are always grouped you can easily do this with a formula.  In E2 put `=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=COUNTIF($B:$B,$D2),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D2,$B:$B,0)+COLUMN(A:A)-1),"")` then copy over and down till you get blanks.

Answer (score 0):

In vba:

```
Sub ffff2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Dim inptrowed As Long
Dim cntrng As Long
Dim lstrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet6") 'Change to your sheet

lstrow = ws.Evaluate("MATCH(""ZZZ"", D:D)")

cntrng = 2 'Start row on D

Do Until cntrng > lstrow
    Dim inptrowst As Variant
    inptrowst = ws.Evaluate("MATCH(D" & cntrng & ",B:B,0)")
    If Not IsError(inptrowst) Then
        inptrowed = ws.Evaluate("COUNTIF(B:B,D" & cntrng & ")")
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(inptrowst, 1), ws.Cells(inptrowst + inptrowed - 1, 1))
        ws.Cells(cntrng, 5).Resize(, inptrowed).Value = Application.Transpose(rng)
    End If
    cntrng = cntrng + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

---

This can also be accomplished with a formula, Put in E2 and copy over and down:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=COUNTIF($B:$B,$D2),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D2,$B:$B,0)+COLUMN(A:A)-‌​1),"")
```

[image]

---

**NOTE**

Both of these methods only work if the ID's are grouped like your example.